# Does php support 64-bit ieee float

Tags: php

I have done a deep reserach on this topic. But nothing is clear about this question. Can anyone help me out with this. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
Nothing is properly described this link prperly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes it does.

---

#### From the PHP Manual..

> The size of an integer is **platform-dependent**, although a maximum value
> of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
> 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does
> not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using
> the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant
> PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

Also..

> If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9
> = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have
> enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even
> a notice will be issued when this happens!

Exerpts from the inner links of PHP Manual to a 3rd Party site...

> PHP is **dynamically typed** and will often convert implicitly between
> strings and floating-point numbers (which are platform-dependant, but
> typically **IEEE 64 bit values**). To force a value to floating-point,
> evaluate it in a numerical context: `$foo = 0 + "10.5";`

But if you are looking to play around with floats and precisions you need to use the [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) functions.

Answer (score 2):

Values stores inside https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend.h#L322

For float use double type. [Size of float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589690/1503018).

So, php support 64-bit ieee float.